# I want to be able to separate sentences/words through a string line

Tags: c#, string, listbox, line

So I'm going to try to explain myself better than my other post. I have two example sentences:

`NEIGHBORHOOD X ADIDAS CONSORTIUM SUPERSTAR 80 10TH ANNIVERSARY -- BLACKGREY                                                 21`

and

`ADIDAS STAN SMITH - RED                                                 22`

I need a code to get out the product name , the quantity (aka 1st number) and the individual price (aka 2nd number). I tried with substring and length but I couldnt make it.
Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: You'll probably want to check out Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure the format of your string will alwyas be the same and those two integers will always be there, I'd suggest you could use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) with char separator `' '` and linq as follows(with description):

```
int[] integersInMyString = myString     .Split(new char[] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) //splitting all the parts by a space (' ') and removing empty entries
                                        .Where(part => int.TryParse(part, out value))                   //selecting only the substrnigs that are integers
                                        .Select(int.Parse)                                              //converting the strings to integers, since we've already filtered the ones we can convert
                                        .ToArray();                                                     //getting the array from the ienumerable
```

After that you could simply access your two needed integers by using:

```
integersInMyString[0] //the first integer a.k.a the quantity
integersInMyString[1] //the first integer a.k.a the individual price
```

According to the product name, I couldn't understand which part exactly should it be. Maybe you could use [String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) with an instance of [String.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) if you know what's coming right after the name.

You could be more specific with your question, I'll be glad to help you out.

P.S.: Not enough reputation to comment, excuse me if my answer is not good enough... Trying to help!

Answer (score 0):

Done it with this snippet of code together with a for each loop.Thank you for the help man :)

```
string[] caracteresnastring = item.Split(new char[] { ',' }.ToArray());
            string code = caracteresnastring[0];
            string name = caracteresnastring[1];
            string price = caracteresnastring[2];
            string quantity = caracteresnastring[3];
```